# install eclipse via terminal

Tags: linux, eclipse

I am trying to install eclipse in a linux box via terminal using below command but it doesn't work.

```
wget "http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/luna/SR2/eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz&mirror_id=454"
```

When it gets downloaded, I see this file name which is wrong?

```
download.php?file=%2Ftechnology%2Fepp%2Fdownloads%2Frelease%2Fluna%2FSR2%2Feclipse-jee-luna-SR2-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz
```

Instead it should be - `eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz` What's wrong?

I renamed the file to correct name and tried untarring it but I get an error as shown below:

```
tar -xvzf eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

What's wrong?

Comment: The filename doesn't matter.  What's in the file?

Comment: @SLaks I updated the question as I got an error while untarring the file.

Comment: If you click that link, you'll see that it's a webpage (which happens to redirect to a download), not a tar file.

Answer (score 4):

***Using wget for eclipse Java***

#### command is :

> wget http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/download.eclipse.org/eclipseMirror/technology/epp/downloads/release/2022-03/202203101200/eclipse-java-2022-03-R-linux-gtk-aarch64.tar.gz

You can change the release of eclipse in the URI. See this [link](http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/download.eclipse.org/eclipseMirror/technology/epp/downloads/release/) for more information. I hope that's useful for you.

Comment: Take a look at my response below - there is a screenshot and instructions on how to browse all releases to get directly links.

Answer (score 3):

Any URL which includes `download.php` will have this problem with `wget`, even the so called "Direct Link".

With more recent download pages however, there is a way to find the actual URLs, and that's to look inside the `xml` file that `download.php` uses for mirror selection.

For example, if we go to the [Eclipse IDE 2020-03](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/2020-03/R/eclipse-inst-win64.exe) page, most of the URLs are `download.php` links, but in the "Other options for this file" side bar, we can see an [xml](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/2020-03/R/eclipse-inst-win64.exe&format=xml) link.

If we navigate there with our web browser and then look at the page source, we can see the actual file URL used by every mirror. Depending on the Web Browser used, the page may be blank, in which case we need to look at the Page Source to see the raw `xml` and thus the URLs.

For me, in the UK, the UK mirror service site would be my best option:

```
<mirror url="http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/download.eclipse.org/eclipseMirror/oomph/epp/2020-03/R/eclipse-inst-win64.exe" label="[United Kingdom] UK Mirror Service (http)" />
```

These (actually) direct URLs do work with `wget`.

Comment: Take a look at my response below - there is a screenshot and instructions on how to browse all releases to get directly links.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like issue with the download link form eclipse website itself.

Please try with the below URL (I have tested it in Ubuntu 14 and its working)

http://eclipse.stu.edu.tw/technology/epp/downloads/release/luna/SR2/eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-linux-gtk.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

Using a Debian variant?

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse
```

Otherwise, I think you just copied the link from the main Eclipse download page, which is a link to another page which grabs the fastest mirror for the download of the file.

For example, the link it gave me is this, which downloads fine

`http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/pub/software/eclipse/technology/epp/downloads/release/luna/SR2/eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz`

After that, the answer is mostly contained on [AskUbuntu: How to install Eclipse?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26632/how-to-install-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

If you're Using **Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS**

**$ wget  file-link**

Downloaded file might look like this :- 
 **download.php?file=%2Foomph%2Fepp%2F2022-06%2FR%2Feclipse-inst-jre-linux64.tar.gz**

Execute following command:

1.First Move to download directory. 
2.Execute tar **-xvf** eclipse-inst-jre-linux64.tar.gz
3.Move to Dir - **cd eclipse-installer**
4. Execute **./eclipse-inst.** It will ask you which dev mode you want to install please select and click next.

Once installed successfully you will get can see launch icon.

Answer (score 0):

Use a console version of oomph installer:

1. Download [Console Oomph Installer](https://search.maven.org/search?q=a:org.eclipse.oomph.console.product), choose the appropriate download for your target platform (zip or tar.gz), example for Linux:

   ```
   wget -O installer.tar.gz  https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/github/a-langer/org.eclipse.oomph.console.product/1.0.1/org.eclipse.oomph.console.product-1.0.1-linux.gtk.x86_64.tar.gz
   ```
2. Extract archive and change current directory:

   ```
   tar -xvzf installer.tar.gz
   cd eclipse-installer/
   ```
3. Install "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers":

   ```
   ./eclipse-inst -nosplash -application org.eclipse.oomph.console.application -vmargs \
   -Doomph.installation.location="$PWD/ide" \
   -Doomph.product.id="epp.package.java"
   ```
4. Wait for the installation to complete, last version of Eclipse will be installed in "$PWD/ide".

   ```
   LATEST
   |############################################################|100%
   ```

More examples see in https://github.com/a-langer/eclipse-oomph-console.

Comment: I was trying this, but it gets stuck at 74%. Also is there any way to specify not the latest version? LTS version or like 2022-12 ?

Comment: You can specify a specific version through a colon:  

`./eclipse-inst -nosplash -application org.eclipse.oomph.console.application -vmargs 
  -Doomph.installation.location="$PWD/ide" 
  -Doomph.product.id="epp.package.java:2022-12"`  
  
This information can be found in the instructions https://github.com/a-langer/eclipse-oomph-console.